# VB.Net Select Nested Json With Same Name

Tags: json, vb.net

example json (snippet taken from a valid json

```
"items": {
"average": 564,
"head": {
  "id": 99161,
```

i already know how to display and select values from this i currently use

```
average.text = If(jResults("average") Is Nothing, "", jResults("average").ToString())
id.text =If(jResults("items")("head") Is Nothing, "", jResults("items")("head")("id").ToString())
```

however i am unsure how to extract the stat values from the following snippet as stat is used multiple times

```
"items": {
"averageItemLevel": 564,
"averageItemLevelEquipped": 564,
"head": {
  "id": 99161,
  "stats": [
    {
      "stat": 32,
      "amount": 651,
      "reforgedAmount": -434
    },
    {
      "stat": 5,
      "amount": 2001
    },
    {
      "stat": 36,
      "amount": 1544
    },
    {
      "stat": 7,
      "amount": 3362
    },
    {
      "stat": 49,
      "amount": 434,
      "reforged": true
    }
  ],
  "armor": 2244
},
```

im unsure how to extract each stat and place it in a different box using the string i used before

```
average.text = If(jResults("average") Is Nothing, "", jResults("average").ToString())
```

i understand i may have to use select case but im not sure how to use my existing string to determine each stat

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'd have to use an array index on "stats", so that in your example JSON, you could get the first two values using

```
jResults("items")("head")("stats")(0)("stat").ToString() ' = "32"
```

and

```
jResults("items")("head")("stats")(1)("stat").ToString() ' = "5"
```

So if for instance you wanted to total all of the "stat" fields, you could do it like so:

```
    Dim statTotal As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To jResults("items")("head")("stats").Count - 1
        statTotal += CInt(jResults("items")("head")("stats")(i)("stat"))
    Next
```

(Of course, in the real world you'd check to make sure each one is not Nothing and that IsNumeric() is true before just throwing a CInt() in there.)

Hope that helps!

Comment: would it be possible for you to give me an example of the array?

Comment: I’m calling jResults("items")("head")("stats") an array, because it’s made of things you access with a number instead of a name. To get the first thing inside stats, you'd put a **(0)** on the end, like jResults("items")("head")("stats")(0). That gives  
`{  
  "stat": 32,  
  "amount": 651,  
  "reforgedAmount": -434  
}`  
If you want just the "stat" value, add **("stat")** on the end, like jResults("items")("head")("stats")(0)("stat"). That gives you the 32.
Similarly, you can get the second item by using (1), the third group by getting (2), etc.